Typesetting phantom contents for NiceTabular

I want to create exam answers using nicematrix

When I print the exam, the table does not typeset but creates phantom contents and draws rulers under the baseline for the answers
A preferred position for the rulers is at the baseline of the answers
The ruler should be of customizable size and color with defaults being 0.4pt and gray
Printing contents of the table should be based on a boolean called examprint

MWE
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newboolean{examprint}
\setboolean{examprint}{true}

\NewDocumentCommand{\phantomNiceMatrix}{m}
{
    \ifbool{examprint}%
    {%
        \RowStyle[nb-rows=#1,color=white]{}
    }%
    {%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{NiceTabular}[cell-space-limits=0.50ex]{@{}l l l l @{}}
    
%   \phantomNiceMatrix{4}
    
    \smash{\rlap{\rule{7.5em}{0.1pt}}}%
    A
    & B
    & C
    & D
    \\
    
    E
    & F
    & G
    & H
    \\
    
    I
    & J
    & K
    & L
    \\
    
    M
    & N
    & O
    & P
    \\
    
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, opacity=0.75, inner sep=0pt, color=gray]
    
        \draw[line width=0.4pt] (2-|1) -- (2-|5);
        
        \draw[line width=0.4pt] (3-|1) -- (3-|5);
        
        \draw[line width=0.4pt] (4-|1) -- (4-|5);
        
        \draw[line width=0.4pt] (5-|1) -- (5-|5);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

    
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


I'm not sure to understand exactly what you wish. Here is a suggestion.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newboolean{examprint}
\setboolean{examprint}{true}

\NewDocumentCommand{\phantomNiceMatrix}{m}
{
    \ifbool{examprint}%
    { \RowStyle[nb-rows=#1,color=white]{} }%
    { }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{NiceTabular}[cell-space-limits=0.50ex]{@{}l l l l @{}}
    % \phantomNiceMatrix{4}
    A
    & B
    & C
    & D
    \\
    E
    & F
    & G
    & H
    \\
    I
    & J
    & K
    & L
    \\
    M
    & N
    & O
    & P
    \\
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.75, inner sep=0pt, color=gray,line width=0.4pt]
        \draw (row-1-base-|1) -- (row-1-base-|last);
        \draw (row-2-base-|1) -- (row-2-base-|last);
        \draw (row-3-base-|1) -- (row-3-base-|last);
        \draw (row-4-base-|1) -- (row-4-base-|last);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


